# Can I install Linux without a disk and remove my Windows completely?

Tags: usb

I have an old laptop with Windows 7. Just for fun, I'd like to replace the current OS with Linux; completely removing Windows.

Edit: Preferably Ubuntu.

Can this be done without a blank disc? Can USB be used instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of linux you want on there but yes you can use usb.

Here is how to do it for centos

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows